# Passing snapshot to an outer function and receiving data from it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Firebase here but my question is more general, and not related to Firebase (I think)

Firebase has a snapshot function that serves has a listener for changes:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";

const db = getDatabase();
const starCountRef = ref(db, 'posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  updateStarCount(postElement, data);

});
```

I'm trying to put that logic in a separate function and receive my changes in my component. The outer function:

```
export function messagesListener() {
  const db = getDatabase();
  const messagesRef = ref(db, "messages");
  return onValue(messagesRef, (snapshot) => {
    console.log('THERE HAS BEEN A CHANGE');
    const data = snapshot.val();
  });
}
```

And in my component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = messagesListener();
  }, []);
```

But that's incorrect (I don't know how to use that listener to retrieve new data form the snapshot when there is a change). What would be a correct way to do it so that I receive data from the snapshot that resides in that messagesListener function?

Comment: "But that's incorrect" could you be more specific? What issues are you facing?

Comment: I don't know hot to use that listener constant to retrieve new data from the snapshot. I'll fix it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try creating a custom hook for that:

```
function useValueUpdate() {
 const [value, setValue] = useState();
 
 const db = getDatabase();
 const starCountRef = ref(db, 'posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
 onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  setValue(data);
 });

 return value;
}
```

so that it can be used in a component like this:

```
const dbValue = useValueUpdate();
useEffect(() => {...}, [dbValue]);
```

Comment: This answer is great I would just like to add that you still have to modify it because as it is, an infinite loop will be created so you have to wrap the snapshot logic with useEffect

Comment: @sir-haver hm, where? In the connection part? You may edit the answer, but I'm not sure what loop are you talking about